# Deleting files appears to work, but doesn't

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, file-permissions

I am attempting to delete a moderately large directory on a network shared drive. Each time I do this (using the Windows Explorer), the deletion appears to work and the file is removed from the display. But it has not been deleted and reappears when the view is refreshed.

Trying the same thing from the command window (using `del /f/s/q MyDir`), the command appears to succeed and a large number of files are shown as having been deleted, but they are still present on the disk.

No errors of any sort appear anywhere. Rebooting the machine doesn't clear the problem. The files are of numerous different types, including some hidden files.

Does anyone know what causes this, or what I can do to get rid of these files?

Answer (score 0):

If the files you are trying to delete is some sort of Windows OS files, they sometimes resurface shortly after the deletion. - Syncronized files can cause a similar problem. Make sure the files on the share are not syncronized with another unit, server or smartphone.

Knowing Windows, it could be just a "Freak Incident" without explanation. - I have somtimes used this Work-around to kill undeletables: Instead of DELETE, try to MOVE the folder or files to another drive (PC, folder or moveable device), which can be deleted after reboot.

Oops, .. just realized that it might be the ROOT of the share folder, you are trying to delete(??). - In that case I would recommend canceling the network share while deleting.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of moving the files, which produced an "access is denied" message, which seems like a clue. Thanks anyway.